# Blazor two-way bind not detected when is updated from JS

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a simple two-way binded component:

```
<input type="text"  id="myInput" bind="@MyVar" />
...
@functions {
    private string MyVar { get; set; } = "foo";
```

All runs fine when I write text on input box. But, if input value is set from javascript then blazor is no able to detect the changed value.

```
document.getElementById('myInput').value='Random Value';
```

I tried to raise some events on element like 'key pressed' and so but the private var MyVar has no changes on blazor client side.

I would like to send back to blazor some values from client, I guess changing value of a hidden input may be solution, but not working.

Comment: I believe it is not intended to work that way, why do you want this?

Comment: hi mr @flores, thanks about your comment, see answer to your comment below Isaac's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Blazor attaches itself to the onchange event you can make this work by triggering the 'onchange'-event on the element after you've set it.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myInput');
element.value = 'Random Value';
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));  //<--makes Blazor see the change
```

There is in many cases no need to reinvent everything when you can use existing javascript-libraries.

Answer (score 4):

When you enter a value into the input box an event is raised, and thus Blazor knows of that, and it updates the property ( MyVar ) to which the input box is bound (this is slso how Angular two-way binding works), but when you change the value of the input box from JavaScript, Blazor has no way to know about this occurrence.

But, hey, why would you do such a thing ?

To send data from JavaScript to Blazor, you shoud define a public and static method in Blazor, annotated with the attibute  [JSInvokable], and a JavaScript function that calls this method:

```
[JSInvokable]
public static Task SendMessageAsync(string message)
{
    // Do something with message
}

DotNet.invokeMethodAsync(assemblyName, 'SendMessageAsync', "Hello Blazor");
```

Read more here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/07/25/blazor-0-5-0-experimental-release-now-available/

Comment: *But, hey, why would you do such a thing ?* Because I have a complex treeview control and I want to send 'expanded' and 'selected' node events to blazor functions. I can't call a static method, I want to call the code that has de state. You know you can bind a method to 'onClick'. But I can't bind methods to 'onNodeSelected' or 'onNodeExpanded' then I think a hidden input with binded values can act as a proxy (with js I change input hidden values when tree events are raised )

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment entirely. Anyhow, you can also call an instance method. This treeview control of yours, I guess it is written in JavaScript, isn't it ? If so, I my humble opinion you should convert it into Blazor: components, events, etc. This is the way to go. Otherwise, there is nosense in using Blazor.

Comment: Hi Issac, you are right about to convert JS control to Blazor, this is the way. Do you know some 'complex' control I can take as example? ( this one looks nice: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-cascading-dropdownlist-in-blazor-using-ef-core-d230bb5bff5f )

Comment: Hi danni, here is a link to how to create a cascading DropDownList in Blazor: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/320/improved-cascading-dropdowns-with-blazor
The one you aluded to is, to my mind, not recommanded.

Here is also a link to a complex component, which you may find very useful: https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorContextMenu

See this as well: https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor
                  https://github.com/BlazorExtensions
      https://blazor.net/community.html
      https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html

Comment: hi Isaac, thanks a lot about your help. I changed the perspective and I converted control to blazor, as you suggested. Here is the result: https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/BlazorServerTree

Comment: not everything can be converted to blazor, one of the reasons we have js interop