# Calling an instance method using JSInterop - Notifying Blazor on input field change with JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Placed here for the sake of it, originally I wrote this question on [Blazors subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/f9uhtx/calling_an_instance_method_using_jsinterop/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) as it was an odd question.

**Problem:**

I need to call StateHasChanged to let Blazor know I've changed the input fields with JS (A library I have to implement, I'm stuck with this regardless so I need to find this solution.)

**Description and solutions I've tried:**

I've checked an issue created 2 years back, but it does not solve my issue as each time I follow their advice of dispatching the 'change' event, nothing happens. Although, that was tested by dispatching the event on the body element since it's difficult to pin point the exact element that needs to be updated. So my current solution is trying to call StateHasChanged in hopes I can get Blazor to see the changes to the field inputs.

**Other info I found:**

Checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748825/blazor-two-way-bind-not-detected-when-is-updated-from-js), but they don't show calling an instanced method, they just mention it's possible but not how.

Second, I checked [here](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/calling-dotnet-from-javascript/), but I'd prefer not to pass around an instance of a component, just to call StateHasChanged.

Maybe I don't absolutely need to call StateHasChanged and I'm just dispatching the 'change' event improperly but there's no good examples of dispatching that event to Blazor anyway so maybe that's an even better solution.

Additional [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803207/how-to-update-c-sharp-value-in-blazor-using-javascript) I've tried.

Edit 1:

I have now managed to call StateHasChanged, mind you not the way I would like it to be called but I called it, and it made no difference, Blazor still doesn't recognize the changed inputs. Guess I'll be trying the 'change' event stuff.

code:

```
//button in Blazor component:
<button type="button" u/onclick='async (e) => await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Task>("ChangeValueFromJs", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this))'>Test</button>

//code in component:
[JSInvokable("invokeFromJS")]
public Task ChangeValue()
{
    StateHasChanged(); 
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

//Javascript on client side page:
function ChangeValueFromJs(wrapper) {
    return wrapper.invokeMethodAsync("invokeFromJS")
        .then(_ => {
            console.log('state has changed');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2 (Solution):

So I ended up going the JS route dispatching the 'change' event as a [solution from SteveSandersonMS](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15817#issuecomment-404307199) on an issue someone made on the Blazor repo very similar to mine. I did however learn two things that are very important for using this solution.

1. The event target for this `dispatchEvent
   (element.dispatchEvent('change', { 'bubbles' : true }))`, element in
   this case, must be the input field, received from a `querySelector
   (let element = document.querySelector("#input-field-username"))`
2. Bubbling should be true, although I haven't tested this, I think
   someone mentioned it in one of my referenced pages that it is
   important.

```
// Not the greatest but - submits an update for *all* input fields, not only the changed ones, maybe improve this later.
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".address-form-input");
if (elements) 
    elements.forEach(p => p.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true })))
```

Hopefully this helps anyone out there, cheers.